# Mac OS X Cursors do not work in ncursers (rtorrent) application

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, rtorrent, ncurses

I have 2 Mac OS X 10.6.5 systems and installed rtorrent using: brew install rtorrent

On my MacBook (MacBook3,1, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.2GHz) rtorrent works fine.
However on my Mac mini (Macmini4,1, Intel core 2 Duo, 2.4GHz) rtorrent starts but the cursors send ABCD which alters the torrent ratios instead of browsing the torrent list.

The cursors should send \033[A etc but they do not seem to be escaped correctly in rtorrent. vim works fine.

Working system :
$ otool -L `which rtorrent`

```
/usr/local/bin/rtorrent:  
 /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)  
 /usr/local/Cellar/libsigc++/2.2.8/lib/libsigc-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)  
 /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)  
 /usr/local/Cellar/libtorrent/0.12.6/lib/libtorrent.11.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.6.0)  
 /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.3.0)  
 /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)  
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)  
 /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 40.0.0)  
 /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
```

Broken system:
$  otool -L `which rtorrent`

```
/usr/local/bin/rtorrent:  
 /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)  
 /usr/local/Cellar/libsigc++/2.2.8/lib/libsigc-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)  
 /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)  
 /usr/local/Cellar/libtorrent/0.12.6/lib/libtorrent.11.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.6.0)  
 /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.3.0)  
 /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)  
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)  
 /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 40.0.0)  
 /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
```

The only difference with the compiled libraries is the /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib and I have tried the older (working version) on the broken system and it did not fix anything.

Can any one suggest a way of getting the cursors working in rtorrent an ncursers application?

Comment: What does `echo $TERM` give on each?

Comment: It is xterm on both.

Comment: I worked through a similar-sounding problem in http://superuser.com/questions/130155/arrow-keys-dont-work-in-htop-on-os-x-in-terminal The eventual workaround there (at bottom of the question) was to compile ncurses through Homebrew and re-build the Homebrew-based *ntop* with that version of ncurses. You could try the same for *rtorrent*.

Comment: Any particular reason why a 6 year old question just got a down vote? It is not relevant to the current home brew issues since it has been sent to the boneyard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.uponmyshoulder.com/blog/2010/os-x-10-6-3-broke-ncurses/) Currently OS X 10.6.3 - 10.6.5 the ncursers library is broken. A hacky fix is to copy the libraries from 10.6.2. I have put my working copies in a public drop box.

```
$ sudo cp /usr/lib/libncurses.5.dylib /usr/lib/libncurses.5.dylib.backup
$ sudo cp /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib.backup

$ cd /usr/lib/
$ sudo wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8462176/osx-10-6-working-ncurse/libncurses.5.dylib
$ sudo wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8462176/osx-10-6-working-ncurse/libncurses.5.4.dylib
```

Comment: According to [Apple Open Source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/), the system-supplied ncurses was changed in 10.6.3, but was reverted in 10.6.4 (back to the version included with 10.6.2; it stayed that way in 10.6.5). Open the page for each release and search for “ncurses” to see which Apple version was used in each release. This implies that correct 10.6.4 and 10.6.5 installations should be OK. Maybe something was left out when you applied the system updates. You could try (re)applying the 10.6.5 combo update.